# phpmyadmin databases display issue on live server

Tags: phpmyadmin, cpanel

When I try to access PHPMYADMIN panel via my server cpanel it displays me a page with logo and welcome message but not list of databases I created
[Here is screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxwZZ.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like the login page, but incomplete. Have a look at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net/STABLE/ to see what I mean. Did you ask your host provider's support about it?

Answer (score 0):

First off clear your cache , it resolve a large amount of these cPanel issues. Secondly try accessing phpmyadmin from WHM instead. If this works then it seems that your cPanels user no longer has permission to access the databases it is trying to load. This can easily be updated using Database Map Tool within WHM if you're not sure how to set it over SSH.

If both fail I'd suggest contacting the hosts to advise.